# XSSFColor with Apache POI 4: cell background color gets overwritten by another cell background color

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm running the following code with Apache POI 4.1.2:

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Cell one");

        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        Color green = new Color(20, 230, 18);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(green, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
        style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("cell two");
        Color red = new Color(200, 30, 18);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(red, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
        style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_DIR + "colors.xlsx");
        outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
            wb.write(fileOut);
        }
        wb.close();
```

the output document ha both cells with red background: it seems that setting red background on second cell has the effect of overwriting the first cell background color.

If I set the background **only on the first cell**, the background color is correctly set to green.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The color is not stored in the cell but in the cell style. So you need creating as much cell styles as colors are needed. Currently you create only one cell style.

Comment: Oh my God, my mistake! Thank you so much

Comment: Please don't use comments to answer a question - turn the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is not stored in the cell but in the cell style. So you need creating as much cell styles as colors are needed.

But also don't simply create a cell style for each cell. There are [Excel limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for maximun number of unique cell formats/cell styles. If that limit gets exceeded then the workbook gets corrupt.

So on workbook level create as much cell styles as needed. Then apply those cell styles while filling cell values into the sheet.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreateExcelDifferentCellColors {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  
  // on workbook level create as much CellStyles as needed
  XSSFCellStyle greenCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  java.awt.Color green = new java.awt.Color(20, 230, 18);
  greenCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(green, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
  greenCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);  
  
  XSSFCellStyle redCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  java.awt.Color red = new java.awt.Color(200, 30, 18);
  redCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(red, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
  redCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

  List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
  numbers.add(12); numbers.add(-12); numbers.add(12.1); numbers.add(-12.1); numbers.add(12.123); numbers.add(-12.123);

  int r = 0;
  for (Number number : numbers) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r++); 
   XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0); 
   cell.setCellValue(number.doubleValue());
   if (number.doubleValue() < 0d) {
    cell.setCellStyle(redCellStyle);
   } else {
    cell.setCellStyle(greenCellStyle);   
   }
  } 

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelDifferentCellColors.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```